# What happened to the -e option for pip?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

[The pip documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html) mentions `-e` option to pip, and this is also used on [some BuildBot developer 'getting started'](http://trac.buildbot.net/wiki/RunningBuildbotWithVirtualEnv) notes. However, I  have pip 1.0.1 and that running:

```
pip -e master
```

reports

```
Usage: pip COMMAND [OPTIONS]

pip: error: no such option: -e
```

Version 1.0.1 of pip seems to be the latest, in that running pip to upgrade itself does not download a newer version. What happened to the `-e` option?

Comment: No one liked it, and it ran away to a far off land.

Comment: [some BuildBot developer 'getting started'](http://trac.buildbot.net/wiki/RunningBuildbotWithVirtualEnv)  dead link

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's still there! But, **-e** is an option only to `pip install`, not to `pip` itself.

```
$ pip install -e
Usage: /usr/local/bin/pip install [OPTIONS] PACKAGE_NAMES...

/usr/local/bin/pip install: error: -e option requires an argument
```

Comment: Great. I have fixed the use of pip on the buildbot wiki.